# Magento 2 upgrading from V 2.1.3 to V 2.2.6 Error

Tags: magento2, magento-upgrade

I am trying to upgrade my website from Magento V2.1.3 to Magento V2.2.6 and it's successfully upgraded. But when I'm opening website it's returning error shown below image.

[image]

Any help on this to resolve.

Comment: it is a known issue check here https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/11113

Comment: @BilalUsean, I followed the steps, still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

While you upgrade magento 2 version at that time this attribute related issue you will face because magento team has changed some attributes from XML standard.

So, error which you are facing "Element 'script', attribute 'data-requiremodule': The attribute 'data-requiremodule' is not allowed.
Line: 42"

That is related to "data-requiremodule" argument from  is not allowd.

So, first of all you need to check in to your custom theme or in third-party module. so, for that you can use grap command from SSH like below.

```
grep "data-requiremodule" app/ -rsn
```

you will find a list of files which contains "data-requiremodule". Remove "data-requiremodule" argument from  tag and check.

Might be above solution will help you.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, removed now showing error **Element 'remove': This element is not expected. Expected is one of** Any suggestion?

Comment: Search with "remove" using grap command and you will find list. If My answer help full to you then please up vote so, might be helpful to other. :)